# ng-model: Radio input not updating in response to model changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

After reading Angular's documentation on [input[radio]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) I saw that you could bind each radio button to a value on your scope/controller using ng-value. However, I'm having trouble getting my view to represent the initial value of my model.

## Controller

```
  $scope.color = {
    name: 'blue'
  };
  $scope.specialValue = {
    "id": "12345",
    "value": "green"
  };
```

## Template

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">Red
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">Green
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
```

This works if the initial value is a simple value ([Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wzW9HBzKwIu6RJkL2w4U?p=preview)).

However, if I try to make the initial value `specialValue`, an object on my scope, things don't seem to work as I'd expect ([Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ViLtvLPjXhBejJpjA2U?p=preview)). I'd expect the initial value to be green, however, the initial value is unselected, and when you select green the model is no longer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's expecting color.name. When you assign $scope.specialValue, you need to do it like `$scope.color = {name: $scope.specialValue}`

Unless you're wanting the value `green` to display, then your ng-value should be `ng-value="specialValue.value"`

Answer (score 0):

Change `<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">Green` to `<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue.value">Green`.

You're assigning an object instead of the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model accesses the color.name property. When doing $scope.color = $scope.specialValue as in your second plnkr you no longer have a name attribute, only id and value.

Your intial `color` object looks like this:

```
$scope.color = {
  name: "red"
}
```

after doing the `$scope.color = $scope.specialValue` your object looks like this

```
$scope.color = {
  id: "12345",
  value: "green"
}
```

If you add the second line here you can see that your $scope.color variable is set. But with id and value as attributes - no longer with the name attribute.

```
<tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
<tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
```

I have also added an angular.copy function to create a copy of the object and not reference each other with another.

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/dixCCsTNVrYQ8dmFKVjb?p=preview